# A word for a person who's mixed in two languages

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives

What do you call those whose mother is English woman and father Hindi or other?  a buddy of mine whom I've been seeing for one month and his mother is English and father Hindi/ Urdu, he says that he can speak English like British people. is it possible that he can speak like them? what would you call him native Hindi or English?

Comment: A native speaker of a language is someone who learned that language from birth. It is possible to learn a language later in life and have the equivalent ability in that language as native speakers. Such people are called *fluent*.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is a *simultaneous bilingual* as he learned the two languages from birth.

You can be a bilingual even if you learn a language as a foreign language after you grow up. [Simultaneous bilingualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_bilingualism) means:

> a form of bilingualism that takes place when a child becomes bilingual by learning two languages from birth. According to Annick De Houwer, in an article in The Handbook of Child Language, simultaneous bilingualism takes place in "children who are regularly addressed in two spoken languages from before the age of two and who continue to be regularly addressed in those languages up until the final stages" of language development. **Both languages are acquired as first languages.** This is **in contrast to sequential bilingualism**, in which the second language is learned not as a native language but a foreign language. (emphasis mine)

[Wikipedia]

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is ***[bilingual](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bilingual)***;

> - Using or able to use two languages, especially with equal or nearly equal fluency.

AHD

Comment: That's a great idea to use